# Trying to use Timeout function multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use Timeout function multiple times but it just runs only once. I am trying to achieve second URL after 6 seconds.

First one after 3 seconds, which is working fine. Also tried if else statement but to no effect.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>You will be redirected in 3 seconds</p>
    <script>
        var time = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = 'http://example.com'
        }, 3000);

        var one = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = 'http://google.com'
        }, 6000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by 3 seconds you will already be redirected to example.com so current js execution will be replaced by newly loaded page try to open in separate tabs it shall work

Comment: I don't know what purpose exactly you have for providing this type of feature. as Quentin mentioned, you can't achieve it like this, but if you still want to use it and there no any security bindings, you can make it done using IFRAME. let me know if you need this code using IFRAME

Comment: Do you own/control the pages you would redirect to?

Comment: K D, please do share the IFRAME code. we can increase the time interval also like first page loads after 10 seconds and the next one after 20. Thanks

Emil: no, I don't own the pages.

Answer (score 9):

JavaScript (in this context) runs inside the webpage.

When you leave the page, you destroy the environment the JavaScript is running in.

You can't run a JavaScript function three (or any other number of) seconds after you have navigated to a different page.

Comment: can we achieve it if increase the time interval from 3 to 10 second for one page?

Comment: No. The page the JS was running in that was destroyed when you left the page is still destroyed a further 7 seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Quentin, you cannot make it work with your existing code.

as you requested in your comments, please try following using IFRAME

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>You will be redirected in 3 seconds</p>
    <!-- use your CSS skills to adjust iframe on the page -->
    <!-- You can also decide if you want to hide iframe intially and show it on first load -->
    <iframe id="iframe_window" src='about:blank' style="height:100%;width:100%;"></iframe>
    <script>
        var time = setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById['iframe_window'].src = 'http://example.com';

        }, 3000);

        var one = setTimeout(function () {
           document.getElementById['iframe_window'].src = 'http://google.com';
        }, 6000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this ( Use `"_blank"` in `window.open` instead of `window.location` ).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>You will be redirected in 3 seconds</p>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function () {
             window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank');
        }, 3000);

setTimeout(function () {
    window.open('http://google.com','_blank');
        }, 6000);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use `window.location=""` to assign the location of window. when first `window.location` excuted then it lost the existence of first code and redirected to `www.example.com` page. Now if you want to achieve this then you will have to put another `window.location` in `www.example.com` code.

Comment: thanks Shubham. I tried to close down the tab. like if google tab opens then example tab close down.

I am trying to use window.close() but it's not working.